# Bootstrap 4 component with same padding like card and without custom css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am placing elements on top of my card like so (run snippet):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <span class="float-right">right</span>
    <span>left</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header clearfix">
      <span class="float-right">right</span>
      <span>left</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    Sequi ad provident non. Et ea beatae ipsum sint. Quas omnis libero similique maxime perferendis pariatur aut ut. Alias quo et modi eaque. Et doloremque minima adipisci error quia rem.

Minima quibusdam sunt sint. Id perspiciatis corporis rerum sapiente ullam velit. Ratione ipsam ut voluptates iure et consequatur. Consequuntur nostrum impedit nesciunt ipsa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to make these elements appear on the same indentation like the card content but without using custom css. Note, that using `p-3` or `px-3` or `p-4` and `px-4` have slightly different indentations:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="px-4 clearfix">
    <span class="float-right">right</span>
    <span>left</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header clearfix">
      <span class="float-right">right</span>
      <span>left</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    Sequi ad provident non. Et ea beatae ipsum sint. Quas omnis libero similique maxime perferendis pariatur aut ut. Alias quo et modi eaque. Et doloremque minima adipisci error quia rem.

Minima quibusdam sunt sint. Id perspiciatis corporis rerum sapiente ullam velit. Ratione ipsam ut voluptates iure et consequatur. Consequuntur nostrum impedit nesciunt ipsa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I first thought of putting the elements in a card itself but then I would have to use custom css to make the card body transparent.

Is there a component or layout utility that has exactly the same padding as the card component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the [Padding Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/spacing/) alone won't work since the Card has `1.25rem` padding, and the padding utils range from `1rem` to `1.5rem`. Here are a few workaround options...

**Option 1:**

You could use `px-3`(`1rem`) plus a single margin: `mx-1`(`.25rem`):

```
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="px-3 mx-1 clearfix">
    <span class="float-right">right</span>
    <span>left</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header clearfix">
      <span class="float-right">right</span>
      <span>left</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo 1](https://www.codeply.com/go/KUgLeZCYca)

Note this is still 1 pixel off on either side since the Card has a 1px border. To work around that you'd have to add an invisible border on the top content (eg: `<div class="px-3 mx-1 border border-white clearfix"></div>`)

**Option 2:**

Or, override the `card-header` and `card-body` with `px-3` (or `px-4`) to match the padding on the top content making them all the same...

```
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="px-3">
    <span class="float-right">right</span>
    <span>left</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header px-3 clearfix">
      <span class="float-right">right</span>
      <span>left</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body px-3">
    ..
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo 2](https://www.codeply.com/go/NqgMhborKd)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, although it is not a good practice

```
  <div class="card-header bg-transparent py-0 border-bottom-0 clearfix">
    <span class="float-right">right</span>
    <span>left</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can combine the following classes `mx-1 px-3 border border-white` :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="mx-1 px-3 clearfix border border-white">
    <span class="float-right">right</span>
    <span>left</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header clearfix">
      <span class="float-right">right</span>
      <span>left</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    Sequi ad provident non. Et ea beatae ipsum sint. Quas omnis libero similique maxime perferendis pariatur aut ut. Alias quo et modi eaque. Et doloremque minima adipisci error quia rem.

Minima quibusdam sunt sint. Id perspiciatis corporis rerum sapiente ullam velit. Ratione ipsam ut voluptates iure et consequatur. Consequuntur nostrum impedit nesciunt ipsa.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```